# Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0 (express js server)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I am trying to send form data to my express js backend.

for my backend server i have this in my server.js file

```
import express from 'express';
import { routes } from './routes/routes.js'
import connectdb from './model/db.js'
import { getAll } from './model/db.js';

const app = express();
const {projectRoute, fileRoute} = routes

// json parser
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
  next()
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// database connection 
connectdb()


// router for all the project endpoint
app.use("/project", projectRoute);
// router for all the files endpoint
app.use("/files", fileRoute);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`listening at port ${port}`);
});
```

and in the controller file for the "fileRoute", i'm simply trying to see what gets sent in the `req.body` object.
This is the form data i send

[image: form data sent in request]

But each time i send the request using VS code Thunderclient, i get this error

[image: request headers and result]

> Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0 (express js server)

and when i set the `content-type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` i get req.body sent back as this

```
{   "----------------------------482425439322439335041238\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name": "\"project\"\r\n\r\nHTML Project\r\n----------------------------482425439322439335041238\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"date\"\r\n\r\n2022-08-10\r\n----------------------------482425439322439335041238--\r\n" }
```

i don't understand why this is hapening, can anyone help??

i expected a json body as my result, and when i used a json validator to check this response

```
{   "----------------------------482425439322439335041238\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name": "\"project\"\r\n\r\nHTML Project\r\n----------------------------482425439322439335041238\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"date\"\r\n\r\n2022-08-10\r\n----------------------------482425439322439335041238--\r\n" }
```

it returned `VALID (RFC 8259)`

Comment: Please show what you sent in Thunderclient

Comment: And please format your question a bit nicer! Use `\`\`\``instead of `>`for your JSON body and use correct English syntax, please, like writing I uppercase instead of i. Just edit your code in https://editor.stackoverflow.design/ which is the upcoming editor, then copy'n'paste it back here in Markdown format (toggle at the top right corner there)

Comment: It looks like your request is potentially neither `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` nor json, but `multipart/form-data`. I'd recommend you fix the client, or if this is not possible you need a parser for that format.

Comment: Done @Anatoly .. it's just a simple form, no media files or anything like that

Comment: @Evert But why is that happening?? is there something changing or causing it to be sent that way?? because it's just a simple form with no media file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok .. so i still haven't found a solution to this problem on the internet. Although it did start working normally a few days after posting this question, unfortunately the issue came back and has persisted since.

So instead of crying about it, i decided to create a solution of mine, so i wrote my own body parser middleware based on the result i was getting.
Here's the code

```
export function localBodyParser(req, res, next) {
    if (typeof req.body !== 'object') {
        return next()
    }
    let keys = []
    let val = []
    let inputsArr 
    let finalInputsArr = []
    for (const key in req.body) {
        keys.push(key)
        val.push(req.body[key])
    }
    if (keys.length > 0) {
        if (keys[0].split('')[0] === '-') {
            inputsArr = val[0].split('=')
            for (let i = 0; i < inputsArr.length; i++) {
                const fieldGroup = []
                fieldGroup.push(inputsArr[i].split('\"')[1])
                fieldGroup.push(inputsArr[i].split('\"')[2].split('\n')[2].split('\r')[0])
                finalInputsArr.push(fieldGroup)
            }
            let body = {}
            for (let i = 0; i < finalInputsArr.length; i++) {
                body[`${finalInputsArr[i][0]}`] = finalInputsArr[i][1]
            }
            req.body = body
            return next()
        }
        return next()
    }
    next()
}
```

and referenced it in `server.js` like so

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, type: 'multipart/form-data' }));
app.use(localBodyParser)
```

you have to add the `express.urlencoded({ extended: true, type: 'multipart/form-data' })` because it needs it to work.

If anyone experiences this issue in the future, and finds a better solution, please feel free to add your solution, else you can use this

Comment: Express is perfectly capable of parsing either `multipart/form-data`, `application/json` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` body data with the correct middleware. Things will break if you start setting your own `Content-Type` headers for your requests and sending the form data in a form that doesn't match the content type. In your case, your requests are saying to Express the body data is URL-encoded while it's _actually_ encoded as `multipart/form-data`. This solution fixes a bug in your own code, and its usefulness for others will be (very) limited.

Comment: @robertklep I stopped setting the `content-type` and just sent the form as-is with postman and still got the same error. I reckoned that there was something wrong with my local environment, but my team mates were getting the same error, so i ruled that out. but now i'm starting to think it actually is my local environment causing the issue, cuz it has started working again , without adding my own parser middleware and without me having to do anything

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because:

- you're uploading the data as `multipart/form-data`, as shown in your "Body" screen shot; and
- you're overriding the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`.

The header makes Express think that the body content is JSON-formatted, which it isn't (it's MIME multipart formatted).

To fix this, don't use the "Body > Form" tab in Postman (remove all the fields there) but the "Body > Json" tab.

Comment: Yes I've tried this and it works for sending a json body,  but i created a traditional form with HTML and JavaScript to test sending actual form data, but i got the same error even without setting the Content-type header to `application/json`.

Comment: Are you using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your HTML form? Because you shouldn't.

Comment: No I'm not using `enctype="multipart/form-data` in my html form. There's no enctype at all.

Comment: The `SyntaxError` about invalid JSON? A regular HTML form gets posted as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which your code is set up to handle, so it would make no sense that it complains about invalid JSON.

Comment: yeah .. `SyntaxError` doesn't show up when i use the HTML form, what gets returned as `req.body` is 
`{
  "----------------------------623868451318300446241211\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name": "\"project\"\r\n\r\nHTML project\r\n----------------------------623868451318300446241211\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"projID\"\r\n\r\n7\r\n----------------------------623868451318300446241211--\r\n"
}`

Comment: So it's still being posting as `FormData` (`multipart/form-data`). A browser won't do that unless it was explicitly told to do so.

Comment: yeah that's true, i just remembered that i was submitting the form with javascript fetch and had set content-type header to `multipart/form-data`. But that isn't the problem, cuz i still get the same thing sent back as `req.body`. i think this error is caused by 2 things 
1 - Either the node engine  not being able to decode the form-data properly, or
2 - The body parser isn't parsing the data correctly.